# Calculating the diviend yield for a sector?

Tags: dividends

I have the cash dividend amount for each company and its sec code, how would i go about calculating the dividend yield of the sector?

What other data would I need?

Answer (score 1):

you would need the spot price of each of the companies (cause then you can calculate the yield).

next you would probably need the index weights of each of the companies with respect to its sector weight.

or alternatively you would need the marketcap of the company if you would want to weigh it relative to market cap size.